# how c++ std::function bind to a template function?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, std-function

is there any mechanism that can be used to implement code as follows:

```
// T can be any type
std::function<T(int,int)> tf;

tf = [](int x, int y) -> int{
    return x + y;
};

cout << tf(4, 5) << endl;

tf = [](int x, int y) -> string{
    return "hello world";
}
cout << tf(4,5) << endl;
```

Comment: I don't think you can do that but I have been wrong in the past. I'll wait for somebody to prove me wrong again.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, we need `T` to:

- Be able to type-erase and hold an instance of arbitrary type;
- Be convertible from such an instance;
- Overload the `<<` operator and forward it to the type-erased instance dynamically.

Depending on whether your list of possible types is bounded or not, we can defer much of the heavy lifting to either `boost::variant` or `boost::any` (respectively `std::variant` or `std::any` in C++17 and above).

The `variant` version is straightforward:

```
template <class... Ts>
struct StreamableVariant : boost::variant<Ts...> {
    using boost::variant<Ts...>::variant;

    friend decltype(auto) operator << (std::ostream &os, StreamableVariant const &sv) {
        return boost::apply_visitor([&](auto const &o) -> decltype(auto) {
            return os << o;
        }, sv);
    }
};

// Usage
std::function<StreamableVariant<int, std::string>(int,int)> tf;
```

The `any` version is a bit more involved, as we need to type-erase the streaming functionality manually while we still know the object's type at construction time:

```
struct StreamableAny : boost::any {
    template <class T>
    StreamableAny(T &&t)
    : boost::any{std::forward<T>(t)}
    , _printMe{[](std::ostream &os, StreamableAny const &self) -> decltype(auto) {
        return os << boost::any_cast<T const &>(self);
    }}{ }

private:
    friend std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream &os, StreamableAny const &sa) {
        return sa._printMe(os, sa);
    }

    std::ostream &(*_printMe)(std::ostream &os, StreamableAny const &);
};

// Usage
std::function<StreamableAny(int,int)> tf;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign a callable with a return type different from the one initially used in the `std::function` unless the former is implicitly convertible to the latter. The assignment operator will [not be a candidate](http://eel.is/c++draft/func.wrap.func#con-23).

There is another case in which the return types can differ and is when the return type of the `std::function` object is [`void`](http://eel.is/c++draft/func.require#2):

```
std::function<void(int)> f = [](int) -> int { return 0; }
```

Comment: @wdy - that won't compile because `f` still returns `void` regardless what you assign to it. @Quentin has already provided a good answer if you can use `boost`.